# javascript object expression notation is not working properly

Tags: javascript, object

I am new to javascript language.  The format is given on web, I tried but it giving the undefined result.

```
var name = {
  a : 'a',
  b:'b',c:'c'
};
console.log(name.a);// undefined
console.log(name);// '[object object]'
```

**The output is undefined ? why**

Comment: I checked the output on chrome, firefox and JsBin also..

Comment: Impossible..... Show that jsbin please.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/xereluw/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Good find @Andreas!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a conflict with [window.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name). If you use `name` in a global context, the value is stringified. The solution is to use the variable only within a function context instead, or anywhere outside of global scope:

```js
var f = function(){
  var name = {
    a : "a",
    b : "b",
    c : "c"
  };
  console.log(name.a);
  console.log(name);
}

f();
```

Comment: OP may need more explanation since they are new to javascript

Comment: yeah, it took me a minute to find some info myself :) best kind of question- I had no idea that this was an issue until I saw the question, so I learned something too.

Answer (score 3):

`name` is a [<strike>reserved</strike> predefined word](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm) in javascript

Quote:

> you'd better avoid the following identifiers as names of JavaScript
>   variables. These are predefined names of implementation-dependent
>   JavaScript objects, methods, or properties (and, arguably, some should
>   have been reserved words):

Comment: It's not a reserved word. It's just a preexisting global variable in browsers.

Comment: @FelixKling updated